# How can I get information about the RootDSE with Powershell locally on a Windows 2008 R2 Domain Controller

Tags: powershell, active-directory, ldap, command

I'm trying to use the Get-ADRootDSE command in Powershell on a Domain Controller running Windows Server 2008 R2 but I get the following error message:

> The term 'Get-ADRootDSE' is not recognised as the name of a cmdlet
>   (...)

I wonder if this command can run locally, and what are the pre-requisites to use it within Powershell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**Using Control Panel**

On the Domain Controller, logged as an Administrator go to:

```
Control Panel\System And Security\Administrative Tools
```

Right clic on the shortcut "Active Directory Module for PowerShell"
Choose "Run as Administrator"

A PowerShell prompt will pop-up with the relevant Module loaded.

In the PowerShell prompt run:

```
Get-ADRootDSE
```

**Using PowerShell command**

On the Domain Controller, logged as an Administrator, within Powershell

```
Import-Module Active Directory
Get-ADRootDSE
```